# Vacuum PostgreSQL DB from PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, vacuum

I want to vacuum a PostgreSQL database from PHP.

I have tried this:

```
pg_query($conn,"vacuum analyse;");
```

How can I tell if this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this query before and after running the vacuum query. If 'age' is less after the vacuum than it was before, then the vacuum has run successfully.

```
SELECT age(datfrozenxid) as age FROM pg_database where datname='your_db';
```

Answer (score 4):

First question: why did you do VACUUM **FULL**? It doesn't make sense. It should be practically never called.

Second: Running vacuum from php (presumably webpage) can be problematic. Vacuum can easily take over 3 minutes, which is (if I recall correctly) standard timeout for web requests.

The best solution is to use autovacuum. If you can't use autovacuum - schedule vacuumdb calls using cron.

Comment: Timeout is not a problem, it is a PHP script that is called by cron and wget and carries out several other maintenance tasks.

Comment: If you have access to cron, why don't you just directly call vacuumdb?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it doesn't return an error, it is probably working. Here are the docs on vacuum.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-vacuum.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your vacuum runs for more than a few seconds, you can run "`SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity`" in a postgres client to get a list of currently running queries.  Your VACUUM query should show up there.